# How to prevent Visual Studio 2022 hide ASP.NET Core application console?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 hides console ASP.NET Core application on running. How to configure it to not do that?

Comment: What's your version of Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to properties in solution explorer, in the debug tag of navigate property. There in the launch select project and output type to console application

Comment: There is only "Open debug launch profiles UI" in "Debug" section. And there is no "Output type" there.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project in solution explorer and select properties, from here ensure (under General) that "Output type" is set to "Console Application" as below -

[image]

Comment: It already has "Console Application" output type.